# Why didn't the Chinese or Indians recapture Malacca in 1511?

Tags: trade, south-east-asia

Portugal took Malacca in 1511 and took control of the spice trade between China and India. They seem to have met little effective resistance and no other state seems to have done anything about it.

The Chinese actually did contest control of the Indian Ocean and were successful for a long time, easily defeating the Portuguese when they tried. T[hey just never attacked Malacca with a serious force.](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Tunmen)

What was stopping China, or other Indian sultans, from recapturing the city? It seems that they had access to good quality steel at the time - Indian steel was actually superior - and would have much shorter lines of supply than Portugal. Was there some logistical reason why the city was not retaken, or was there no interest in the first place? Why did Asia sit passively by while Portugal was taking control of the spice trade?

Comment: "Recapturing" implies that some Indian or Chinese state had prior control of Malacca, which isn't the case.

Comment: China simply was not interested in naval affairs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zheng_He#Imperial_China. And of course, if you are going to wage war for some land accross the sea, the steel of your melee weapons is of little use if your ships are send to the bottom of the sea by the Portuguese superior ships and cannon. Consider that the Ottoman Empire tried to dislodge the Portuguese from the Indic Ocean and failed to do so.

Comment: So the answer is basically "they weren't interested" or "they didn't have good cannons"? Alright.

Comment: [Iberian steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toledo_steel) was actually on par if not superior to [Indian steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_and_Steel_Industry_in_India#History).

Comment: @Juan I know this is unrelated, but wasn't the Ottoman Navy dominating Europe until about 1700?

Comment: @Makhnk No, after Lepanto, 1571, the Ottoman Navy was significantly less of a threat.  Piracy and slave trading, however, plagued the Europeans for some time after that.

Comment: Forgive my history knowledge, but was it less of a threat or was it just focused on fighting the Safavids?